# How can I better parse variable time stamp information in Fortran?

Tags: parsing, optimization, timestamp, fortran

I am writing code in gfortran to separate a variable time stamp into its separate parts of year, month, and day. I have written this code so the user can input what the time stamp format will be (ie. YEAR/MON/DAY, DAY/MON/YEAR, etc). This creates a total of 6 possible combinations. I have written code that attempts to deal with this, but I believe it to be ugly and poorly done.

My current code uses a slew of 'if' and 'goto' statements. The user provides 'tsfo', the time stamp format. 'ts' is a character array containing the time stamp data (as many as 100,000 time stamps). 'tsdelim' is the delimiter between the year, month, and day. I must loop from 'frd' (the first time stamp) to 'nlines' (the last time stamp).

Here is the relevant code.

```
* Choose which case to go to. 
first = INDEX(tsfo,tsdelim)
second = INDEX(tsfo(first+1:),tsdelim) + first
if (INDEX(tsfo(1:first-1),'YYYY') .ne. 0) THEN
   if (INDEX(tsfo(first+1:second-1),'MM') .ne. 0) THEN
      goto 1001
   else
      goto 1002
   end if
else if (INDEX(tsfo(1:first-1),'MM') .ne. 0) THEN
   if (INDEX(tsfo(first+1:second-1),'DD') .ne. 0) THEN
      goto 1003
   else
      goto 1004
   end if
else if (INDEX(tsfo(1:first-1),'DD') .ne. 0) THEN
   if (INDEX(tsfo(first+1:second-1),'MM') .ne. 0) THEN
      goto 1005
   else
      goto 1006
   end if
end if

first = 0
second = 0

* Obtain the Julian Day number of each data entry. 
* Acquire the year, month, and day of the time stamp. 
* Find 'first' and 'second' and act accordingly. 

* Case 1: YYYY/MM/DD
1001    do i = frd,nlines
       first = INDEX(ts(i),tsdelim)
       second = INDEX(ts(i)(first+1:),tsdelim) + first
       read (ts(i)(1:first-1), '(i4)') Y
       read (ts(i)(first+1:second-1), '(i2)') M
       read (ts(i)(second+1:second+2), '(i2)') D
* Calculate the Julian Day number using a function. 
       temp1(i) = JLDYNUM(Y,M,D)
end do
goto 1200
* Case 2: YYYY/DD/MM
1002    do i = frd,nlines
       first = INDEX(ts(i),tsdelim)
       second = INDEX(ts(i)(first+1:),tsdelim) + first
       read (ts(i)(1:first-1), '(i4)') Y
       read (ts(i)(second+1:second+2), '(i2)') M
       read (ts(i)(first+1:second-1), '(i2)') D
* Calculate the Julian Day number using a function. 
       temp1(i) = JLDYNUM(Y,M,D)
end do
goto 1200

* Onto the next part of the code
1200 blah blah blah
```

I believe this code will work, but I do not think it is a very good method. Is there a better way to go about this?

It is important to note that the indices 'first' and 'second' must be calculated for each time stamp as the month and day can both be represented by 1 or 2 integers. The year is always represented by 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only six permutations to handle I would just build a look-up table with the whole `tsfo` string as the key and the positions of year, month and day (1st, 2nd or 3rd) as the values.  Any unsupported formats should produce an error, which I haven't coded below.  When subsequently you loop though your `ts` list and split an item you know which positions to cast to the year, month and day integer variables:

```
PROGRAM timestamp
  IMPLICIT NONE

  CHARACTER(len=10) :: ts1(3) = ["2000/3/4  ","2000/25/12","2000/31/07"] 
  CHARACTER(len=10) :: ts2(3) = ["3/4/2000  ","25/12/2000","31/07/2000"] 

  CALL parse("YYYY/DD/MM",ts1)
  print*
  CALL parse("DD/MM/YYYY",ts2)

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE parse(tsfo,ts)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CHARACTER(len=*),INTENT(in) :: tsfo, ts(:)

    TYPE sti
       CHARACTER(len=10) :: stamp = "1234567890"
       INTEGER :: iy = -1, im = -1, id = -1
    END TYPE sti
    TYPE(sti),PARAMETER :: stamps(6) = [sti("YYYY/MM/DD",1,2,3), sti("YYYY/DD/MM",1,3,2),&
                                        sti("MM/DD/YYYY",2,3,1), sti("DD/MM/YYYY",3,2,1),&
                                        sti("MM/YYYY/DD",2,1,3), sti("DD/YYYY/MM",3,1,2)]
    TYPE(sti) :: thisTsfo
    INTEGER :: k, k1, k2
    INTEGER :: y, m, d
    CHARACTER(len=10) :: cc(3)

    DO k=1,SIZE(stamps)
      IF(TRIM(tsfo) == stamps(k)%stamp) THEN
        thisTsfo = stamps(k)
        EXIT
      ENDIF
    ENDDO
    print*,thisTsfo

    DO k=1,SIZE(ts)
      k1 = INDEX(ts(k),"/")
      k2 = INDEX(ts(k),"/",BACK=.TRUE.)
      cc(1) = ts(k)(:k1-1)
      cc(2) = ts(k)(k1+1:k2-1)
      cc(3) = ts(k)(k2+1:)
      READ(cc(thisTsfo%iy),'(i4)') y
      READ(cc(thisTsfo%im),'(i2)') m
      READ(cc(thisTsfo%id),'(i2)') d
      PRINT*,ts(k),y,m,d
    ENDDO
  END SUBROUTINE parse
END PROGRAM timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encode the different cases in another way, like this:

```
module foo
  implicit none
  private
  public encode_datecode
contains
  integer function encode_datecode(datestr, sep)
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: datestr, sep
    integer :: first, second
    character(len=1) :: c1, c2, c3
    first = index(datestr, sep)
    second = index(datestr(first+1:), sep) + first
    c1 = datestr(1:1)
    c2 = datestr(first+1:first+1)
    c3 = datestr(second+1:second+1)
    foo = num(c1) + 3*num(c2) + 9*num(c3)
  end function encode_datecode

  integer function num(c)
    character(len=1) :: c
    if (c == 'Y') then
        num = 0
    else if (c == 'M') then
        num = 1
    else if (c == 'D') then
        num = 2
    else
        stop "Illegal character"
    end if
  end function num
end module foo
```

and then handle the legal cases (21, 15, 19, 7, 11, 5) in a `SELECT` statement.

This takes advantage of the fact that there won't be a 'YDDY/MY/YM' format.

If you prefer better binary or decimal readability, you can also multiply by four or by 10 instead of 3.